# How much corruption does each Constitutional option generate?

Tags: tropico-5

In Tropico 5, Constitution options each add (or subtract?) to your total "corruption %". This is a financial overhead that eats up a portion of your country's income. However, the game is utterly opaque about which options increase corruption and by how much.

How much does each option increase corruption by? (For all 12 options.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I performed a little science and learned the answer. There seems to be a 13% baseline corruption minimum in the Modern Era. It is 13%. This is the lowest corruption value attainable. Earlier phases have higher minimum corruption values. I have not gleaned this particular information yet.

The highest possible corruption value is 39%.

### Colonial Options

#### Voting Rights

All Citizens Vote: +0% Corruption

Male Citizens Vote: +1% Corruption

Wealthy Citizens Vote: +2% Corruption

#### Religion and State

Secular State: +0% Corruption

Theocracy: +2% Corruption

Atheist State: +2% Corruption

#### Armed Forces

Militia: +0% Corruption

Conscription: +1% Corruption

Professional Army: +2% Corruption

### World Wars Options

#### Political Rights

Democracy: +0% Corruption

Police State: +2% Corruption

Totalitarian State: +2% Corruption

#### Labor Policy

Work For All: +0% Corruption

Happy Childhood: +1% Corruption

Workers Paradise: +2% Corruption

#### Citizenship

Immigrants Nation: +0% Corruption

Visa Program: +2% Corruption

Guarded Heaven: +2% Corruption

### Cold War Options

#### Personal Rights

Security Surveillance: +0% Corruption

Total State Control: +2% Corruption

Open Society: +2% Corruption

#### Economy Structure

Free Market: +0% Corruption

Planned Economy: +2% Corruption

Plutocracy: +2% Corruption

#### Media Independence

Independent Media: +0% Corruption

Subsidized Media: +2% Corruption

Total Propaganda: +2% Corruption

### Modern Era

#### Digital Rights

Free Internet: +0% Corruption

Fight Piracy: +1% Corruption

Total Firewall: +3% Corruption

#### Globalization

Open Borders: +0% Corruption

Strategic Sector: +1% Corruption

Protectionism: +2% Corruption

#### Ecology

Energy Efficiency: +2% Corruption

Economy First: +0% Corruption

Zero Emissions: +3% Corruption

The least corrupt government is apparently a secular democracy where every citizen is eligible to vote defended by a militia. Work is mandated for all citizens and retirement is quite late, however, all newcomers are welcome as the immigration policy is lax. This nation practices free market principles augmented by open borders trade agreements and a priority on economic health at some expense to the environment. While it has an independent media and unrestricted internet access, it also has systematic surveillance of its citizens, ostensibly for their safety!

The two big gotchas for me were that Zero Emissions is the greatest source of corruption (tied for first place, technically), and that an Open Society is more corrupt than one with security surveillance!